# Filling a table

Tags: excel

I have data that is organized in the following format

```
Country Code    DATE     VALUE 
UK              2007      5
UK              2008      6 
UK              2009      7 
USA             2007      15
USA             2008      16
USA             2009      17
```

and I want to organize it in the following format

```
      2007    2008    2009
UK     5       6       7 
US     15      16      17
```

Namely, in which each row has all the values of a country.
So now I have the following empty table

```
      2007    2008    2009
UK
US
```

What is the function to be used to fill it?

Comment: Why not try a pivot table instead of a function?

Answer (score 1):

If not pivot table. Formula in F2

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$7=$E2)*($B$2:$B$7=F$1)*($C$2:$C$7))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of pivot table as below.

[image]